# Not able to fetch data from API endpoint in ReactJS?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have created REST API endpoint i.e `localhost:5000/api/match/:match_id`Now I want to fetch data from this endpoint and display it on frontend but I am getting undefined error.

In server.js :

```
//Get a particular match stats
app.get('/api/match/:match_id', (req, res) =>{

    let match = req.params.match_id;

    matches.findOne({id: parseInt(match)}).then(Match =>{

        res.json(Match);
    });

});
```

In matchinfo.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Matchinfo extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            info:[],
            loading:true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/match/:match_id')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        info:res,
        loading:false
      })
    })
    }

  render() {

    if (this.state.loading) {
            return <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
    }

    return (
      <div>
            <p class="match">MATCH {info.id}</p>
            <h4>{info.team1}</h4>
            <p>VS</p>
            <h4>{info.team2}</h4>
            <div class="winner">
            <h3>WINNER</h3>
            <h4>{info.winner}</h4>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Matchinfo;
```

In matchinfo component I am getting failed to compile after loader is finished spinning see screenshot for more clarification.

[image]

[image]

JSON Response :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below updated code. It should work as you expected

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Matchinfo extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            info:[],
            loading:true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/match/:match_id')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        info:res,
        loading:false
      })
    })
    }

    renderLoading(){
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
    }

  render() {
    const {info} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
            {this.state.loading ? this.renderLoading(): ''}
            {this.state.info.length > 0 && (
                <div>
                <p class="match">MATCH {info.id}</p>
                <h4>{info.team1}</h4>
                <p>VS</p>
                <h4>{info.team2}</h4>
                <div class="winner">
                    <h3>WINNER</h3>
                    <h4>{info.winner}</h4>
                </div>
                </div>
                )}     
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Matchinfo;
```

Comment: `this.state.info.team1` , `this.state.info.team2` `this.state.info.winner` nothing works why ?

Comment: Got it. I want to see console.log of this.state.info. Can you do console.log after api response.

Comment: Do console.log in render before return like console.log(this.state.info); let me know what it prints

Comment: I have created the component Matchinfo which will get rendered onclick So I have to still make onclick functionality.

Comment: content.js -> https://jsfiddle.net/moog8nxg/ which displays all match stats and Matchinfo.js -> https://jsfiddle.net/oqL3L712/ which displays single match stats in detail. Now in content.js I can populate my HTML using JSON data by doing `match.winner` , `match.team1` etc. Now I want to do similar in matchinfo.js but it throws error `info` un defined why so ? `match.id` works in content.js but `info.id` does not work in matchinfo.js why ?

Comment: Yeah right. Updated my answer please check. I missed to declare info state i.e., const {info} = this.state; in render. It should be fine now. Check and let me know

Comment: @Hemandri but in content.js I have not done anything like that check jsfiddle code I have not done `const {matches} = this.state;` in content.js but it still works why so?

Comment: @Hemandri Without this `const {matches} = this.state;` can it work ? because check content.js in it I have not done `const {matches} = this.state;` but it still works fine see screenshot https://imgur.com/a/4d5h1

Comment: Man in Content.js you are iterating matches using map but in Matchinfo you are not iterating it because its a single object that you get in response. Thats the difference. This fetch('api/matches') returns list of matches and this fetch('api/match/:match_id') gives only one object that matches the matchid. First understand the functionality.

Comment: @Hemandri I am new to ReactJS and did not know this fact thanks man. If possible can you share your email or if possible can you send me email at aditodkar@gmail.com I almost wasted a day on figuring this out. I want to ask few doubts please message me :)

Comment: Is it working now after adding const {info} = this.state; in your MatchInfo component as I mentioned?

Comment: Can you please help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457339/how-to-make-using-of-react-router-dom-for-routing-in-reactjs/48457569?noredirect=1#comment83908040_48457569